# Where can I find the source code for the TagLib# library?

Tags: c#, .net, taglib, taglib-sharp

Some time ago on the [ID3 Implementations](http://www.id3.org/Implementations) web page I found TagLib# to be quite useful library for handling tags in audio files.
However when I recently tried to get the latest code from the http://developer.novell.com/wiki/index.php/TagLib_Sharp I was sadly disappointed because apparently Novell got rid of the project's page.

Does anyone know if there is any new home page for the project?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't know about a homepage, but the source code is [here](https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp/).

To use taglib-sharp in your own project I would just install the compiled version using NuGet. 
To install TagLib#, run the following command in the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio.

```
PM> Install-Package taglib
```

The NuGet distribution of taglib-sharp can be found at http://nuget.org/packages/taglib.